# Modify array so it will contain data under unique username

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have array that contains plenty of data. Format is always like that:

```
1:
UserName: "John Smith"
Priority: "2"
Time Occured: "02/09/2019 11:20:23"
Time Ended: "02/09/2019 11:20:23"
2:
UserName: "Tom Bill"
Priority: "4"
Time Occured: "01/08/2019 13:20:23"
Time Ended: "04/08/2019 15:20:23"
3:
UserName: "John Smith"
Priority: "2"
Time Occured: "06/08/2019 13:20:23"
Time Ended: "09/09/2019 15:20:23"
...
```

Of course there is more stuff, but just to give you idea of structure.
Array contains entries that might be under the same user name. As user can have multiple entries

What I want to do, is sort and modify it to the way I can use it on data table. I am not sure what approach might be the best or what is possible.

I was thinking that I need to modify array do some math in meantime. So in Data table I can present that John Smith, got 8 entries, two of them are sev 4 etc etc. Tom Bill got 4 entries etc. Basically I won't use original data as I need to modify some parts of it, for Example I am not interested in date itself, but if it was in the past or in the future, already got scripts for that, yet I need to do it for every single user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A structure something like this seems to be sufficient for your requirement:

```
data = {
   'John Smith' : [{ Priority : 1, .... }, { ...2nd instance }],
   'John Doe' : [{...1st instance of John Doe}],
}
```

Basically an object that has the names for keys, and each key has an array of entries of data.

Whenever you wish to add more entries to John Smith, you get access to the array directly by using `data['John Smith']`

**EDIT**

To convert the data to this format.

```js
data = [
  {
    'UserName': "John Smith",
    'Priority': "2",
    'Time Occured': "02/09/2019 11:20:23",
    'Time Ended': "02/09/2019 11:20:23",
  },
  {
    'UserName': "Tom Bill",
    'Priority': "4",
    'Time Occured': "01/08/2019 13:20:23",
    'Time Ended': "04/08/2019 15:20:23",
  },
  {
    'UserName': "John Smith",
    'Priority': "2",
    'Time Occured': "06/08/2019 13:20:23",
    'Time Ended': "09/09/2019 15:20:23",
  }
]


convertData = (data) =>{
  let newData = {}
  
  for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
    // console.log(data[i])
    let name = data[i]['UserName']
    tempData = {
      'Priority' : data[i]['Priority'],
      'Time Occured' : data[i]['Time Occured'],
      //Add more properties here
    }
    
    if (newData[name]==null){
      newData[name] = []
    }
    
    newData[name] = [...newData[name], tempData]
    
  }
  console.log(newData)
}

convertData(data)
```

Look at this codepen.
https://codepen.io/nabeelmehmood/pen/jONGQmX

Comment: yes, it looks like something I can work on, how can I consolidate it like that?

Comment: Let me try this in a codepen and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Check answer now

Comment: Thanks I will take it from now, it should be easier for me, thanks again!